# Firefox ignoring the CSS height of a DIV container

Tags: css, firefox, height

I have a problem that only occurs in firefox and I cannot find a fix for it so it would be great if someonw could help me on this.
I have this page: https://shorturl.at/rwR79
In there is a container which is 100% height. Which shows fine in chrome and Safari but in Firefox the container "orange box" has never the 100% height but stays small.

I cannot figure out what the problem is as its working on all other browsers.
Would be great if someone had an idea on this.
Thanks.

Comment: you can fix it very easily using `vh` instead of `%`, would that be ok for your page?

Comment: Probably not as I want it responsive to adapt to the height of the browser window.

Comment: `vh` is responsive, it stands for viewport-height and it's a percentage of your browser's window, please give it a try :)

Comment: ^can confirm that "height: 100vh;" works in firefox

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi Paulie_D I really like your comment :), I just wanted to ask you, I imagine that what you're saying applied also to demos like in JsFiddle or stackblitz? would you say that it's ok to use those (or personal links as well) if you also provide the code in the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you can just use `vh` instead of `%`

But I have also another nice solution for you if you want to avoid `vh` units, in the `main` class just change the `display` from `table` to `flex`, that seems to be solving the issue nicely in firefox too :) , also you need to add `justify-content: center;` in the class to center everything horizontaly

Comment: Hey Dario, the display: flex didn't work unfortunately but the vh part did. I have never worked with vh before so I thought is was a measurement term. But this worked. Thanks.

Comment: Strange I did try the flex one in the firefox dev tools and did work like a charm :/, well as long as you are ok with the `vh` then it's ok I guess :)